# cannot get the results to be displayed on the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I cannot display the results which I got from database:

```
{"results": ["USA", "Canada"]} 
{"message":"Could not find any countries."} //else
```

I got this error from console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.
```

Could you please check my code to find out what is my mistake.

Here is my view:

```
<a href="#my_div" id="load_country_list">My Travel Plans</a> 
<div id="my_div">             
<div id="country_list_is_got"></div>
<div id="country_list_is_not_got"></div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
if ($this->my_model->did_get_country_list($user_id)) {              
$country["results"]= $this->model_users->did_get_country_list($user_id);            
       echo json_encode($country);          
        }
        else {      
        $country = array('message' => "Could not find any countries." );
            echo json_encode($country);     
        }
```

JS file:

```
$("#load_country_list").click(function() { 

    $.post('cont/get_country_list', function (country) {
        if (country.message !== undefined) {
            $( "#country_list_is_not_got").text(country.message);
        } else {
            $.each(country.results, function(i, res) {
                 var item = $('<div>'),               
                     title = $('<h3>');
                     title.text(res);
                     item.append(title);
                     item.appendTo($("#country_list_is_got"));
            });   
        }
    });
   });
```

Comment: for which variable you have defined lenght?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell jQuery what content type is coming back from the server (`json`)

It defaults to 'string' and it has no reason to think that's incorrect.

See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) for the correct parameter order.
Your `.each` iterator is trying to loop over a string, and - obviously - failing.

---

Edit: As a point of pedantry, why are you using POST to GET data? "Get" is literally in your URL.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have just noticed that:) I even don't understand why people use GET because POST does the same thing and it's secure.

Comment: Whoa whoa, NOTHING coming from the browser is secure, don't fool yourself into thinking that! :)

There are pros and cons to each, but they largely revolve around aesthetics (what's in the URL) and size limits (URLs can only be xxxx bits long).

I highly doubt you will hit the length limitation in this scenario, so that leaves just the aesthetics.
Since you're doing this via ajax, NOTHING will ever appear in the URL to a user - it's all behind the scenes.

At this point, the only thing left to consider is good practices, and RESTful design should get with GET and post with POST.

Comment: Thanks! I just replaced POST with GET and nothing appeared in the URL:) Can I use GET in case if I have a lot of information from db to display?

Comment: Of course! Remember that `GET` and `POST` are just two of a number of [HTTP Protocol Methods or 'verbs'](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html). The way browsers handle them is different because of their differing standards, but when you're opening AJAX connections to a server, it's simply a matter of choosing the right one for the task. If you're getting a bunch of data, it's probably `GET`! :D  On the other hand, if you have a LOT of information to display, it might be worth looking into ways to reduce your request size by paginating your data, or some other method.

Comment: Noted :) You are the best!

Comment: Hi Rockerest! Could you please have a look on this question please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207443/controller-does-not-return-the-message

Answer (score 0):

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/haridharan/N99hs/)try this,  issue is `results contain array.but you try to use key,value`

```
   if (country.message !== undefined) {
        $( "#country_list_is_not_got").text(country.message);
    } else {
        for(i=0;i<country.results.length;i++){
                 var item = $('<div>'),               
                 title = $('<h3>');
                 title.text(country.results[i]);
                 item.append(title);
                 item.appendTo($("#country_list_is_got"));

        }  
    }
```

Comment: I suspect that you aren't familiar with jQuery's [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) iterator. There was/is nothing wrong with his looping code, and if you actually edit your JSFiddle to use the code he had, you'll see that it still works just fine. ----edit: your JSFiddle [edited](http://jsfiddle.net/N99hs/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `$.get` or the `$.getJSON` shortcut, instead of `$.post`

```
$.getJSON("cont/get_country_list", function( data ) {
  console.log(data);

  // something like this for list construction and append to body
  var countries = [];

  // maybe you need data.results here, give it a try or see console
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    countries.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
  });

  $( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "country-list",
    html: countries.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```