# Controller does not return the variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

Form can be successfully submitted via ajax and the notification message can be displayed in jquery window ("Your name has been successfully changed!")but when I submit an empty form it doesn't return the message "fail". Could you please check my code and help me to find my mistake.

Controller:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->load->model('my_model');   

$this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Name','required|trim|alpha|min_length[3]|xss_clean');

if($this->form_validation->run()) {
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    if ($this->model_users->did_change_name($user_id, $name)) {
        $data = array(
            'message_ok' => "Your name has been successfully changed!"
        );
        echo json_encode($data);
    } else { 
        $data = array(
            'message' => 'fail'                   
        );
        echo json_encode($data);         
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the request response in the browser's developer tools (CTRL+I, normally) - the PHP script may be error'ing without you knowing.

Comment: @NiceTry Please take some time to format your code correctly, i did it all for this question but remember is more fun to answer questions when the code is well indented!

Comment: I check in console network, there are not any errors

Comment: Mathieu, thanks for formatting. Actually, I thought it was well formatted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about parentheses :) Try this way:

```
if($this->form_validation->run()) {
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    if ($this->model_users->did_change_name($user_id, $name)) {
        $data = array(
            'message_ok' => "Your name has been successfully changed!"
        );
        echo json_encode($data);
    } 
}
else { 
        $data = array(
            'message' => 'fail'                   
        );
        echo json_encode($data);         
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much:) I have just noticed that :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used CI in a good while, but from my understanding you're checking if the form was valid to run a series of events, such as a name change. But when the form validation returns false that's when one of your validation rules have failed, which it has.

```
if($this->form_validation->run()) {

    // your code

} else {

    $data = array(
        'message' => 'fail'                   
    );
    echo json_encode($data); 

}
```

Comment: when the validation forms returns false, controller should return the message "false" but it doesn't work

Comment: Is nothing being returned, or does it return the successful message? If it's the latter the problem may be in your model.

Comment: when I submit a name, it changes the name successfully and returns the successful message. When I submit an empty form, it does not change the name and does not return the "fail" message.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($this->form_validation->run()==TRUE) {
```

Right now your code is always going to return the first argument because you aren't actually checking the result of the validation. It's currently equivalent to saying if(1)

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: I just tried in the way you described but nothing has been changed